# Page turns blank when I try to show map using google's map api

Tags: javascript, python, html, google-maps, google-app-engine

When the user logs in I want to show a map.

The base html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/static/main.css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=mykey&sensor=true">
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(-20, 110),
      zoom: 8
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
        mapOptions);
  }
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>

<title>myapp</title>
</head>

<body>
{% block content %}
{% endblock %}
</body>

</html>
```

mainpage.html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
<div id="map-canvas"/>
{% endblock %}
```

When I load mainpage, the map doesn't show at all. I looked at the page source, which correctly showed `<div id="map-canvas"/>`, so the map is being loaded, but it isn't showing. Then I added some text

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
<div id="map-canvas"/>
<div>derp<div>
{% endblock %}
```

derp also shows up in the source code but everything is still blank. What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your map-canvas div needs to be sized, as explained in the doc.

Answer (score 0):

`div` is not a so-called [empty element](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/diffs.html#h-4.6)(like e.g. `li, option , img`), it requires a closing tag(also when it doesn't have any content):

```
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

That's the reason why you dont see "derp", for the issue with the map see the answer of bruno desthuilliers.